# How to clear data from lookupedit ? Winform Devexpress

Tags: winforms, devexpress

In my form I have 3 buttons and 1 lookupedit. Lookupedit is disabled initially If i click on button1 it enables and then I select 3rd item(Computer) from lookupedit it displays and i select button2 now lookupedit is disabled. If again i click button1 then that time previously selected 3rd Item(Computer) is display again. How to clear that before selecting ?

Thanks in Advance,
Sri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that you need to clear the selected value in the [LookUpEdit](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsLookUpEdittopic) editor is to set the [EditValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsBaseEdit_EditValuetopic) property to null. This is valid for any DevExpress editor, because all of them has a common structure

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's working fine `lookupedit1.EditValue=Null`